# JQuery tabbed pages content - only the first page shows the sIFR (IE + Safari/PC and Safari/Mac)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sifr

i've just been trying to figure this out...

All is well in Firefox(PC/Mac), but Safari (PC/mac), and 3 versions of IE(6,7,8) are not playing ball - please read on...

Context:
I have a small tabbed content area with 3 alternate content - they each have siFR headers, with exactly the same mark up. I'm using simple jQuery show() and hide(), and the first content is set to show as default.

Problem:
Now the strange thing is that in IE6, 7 + 8 and safari on PC, the sIFR is rendered on the default content but not in the other tabbed content.

Question:
Does this sound familiar to anyone? And can anyone explain what might be causing this?

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this discussion](http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=23434), sIFR won't replace elements that are not displayed (i.e. text in you hidden tabs).

The solution would be to execute calls to `sIFR.replace(...)` when the tab is changed.

---

Another solution is provided in [jQuery UI documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Tabs#Why_does...).